# When is a formulation with min function an ILP problem?

Tags: integer-programming

Consider a simple formulation like the one below.
\begin{align}
\max&\quad\sum_i x_i\\
\text{s.t.}&\quad x_i \leq \underset{\forall j<i}{\text{min}}\ f(x_j)
\end{align}

I am just wondering if I can consider such formulation an ILP problem.

I intentionally kept things undefined to understand if this is general. Hope it sounds.

Comment: Because you are using min (which is a concave function of affine (linear) arguments) in a convexity preserving fashion, @RobPratt 's answer applies. If the inequality constraint were in the other direction ($\ge$ rather than $\le$ ), the min would appear in a non-convex fashion, and that would require binary (integer) variables to model; hence trinng what would  otherwise be an LP into an ILP.  Details: Concave expression $ \ge$ affine (linear) expression is a convex constraint.  Concave expression $ \le$ affine (linear) expression is a non-convex constraint.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your constraint is equivalent to
$$x_i \le f(x_j) \quad \text{for $j<i$},$$
so it is linear if $f$ is linear.

Answer (score 3):

Extending Robs answer slightly, taking into account that you asked about ILP (which I interpret as mixed-integer linear program), the constraint is MILP-representable as long as $f$ is MILP-representable (thus allowing you to have piecewise affine functions such as min/max/abs/general pwa etc)